# Remove extra layer from object

Tags: javascript

I have some web-hook which returns next data:

```
 "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cus_JYmRConwwwbDjw",
      "object": "customer",
      "address": null,
      "balance": 0,
      "created": 1622105261,
      "currency": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "delinquent": false,
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "email": null,
      "invoice_prefix": "7BA9446D",
      "invoice_settings": {
        "custom_fields": null,
        "default_payment_method": "pm_1Ivesgeee6awlUaOWjDDzmv",
        "footer": null
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "name": null,
      "next_invoice_sequence": 1,
      "phone": null,
      "preferred_locales": [],
      "shipping": null,
      "sources": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_JYmRCewwea5bDjw/sources"
      },
      "subscriptions": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_JYmewenGa5bDjw/subscriptions"
      },
      "tax_exempt": "none",
      "tax_ids": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_JYmRCowea5bDjw/tax_ids"
      },
      "tax_info": null,
      "tax_info_verification": null
    },
    "previous_attributes": {
      "invoice_settings": {
        "default_payment_method": null
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "customer.updated"
}
```

To access for example **id** I need to use next path **data.object.id**.
How I can avoid using this not readable, not needed **object** item in path?
What I need is **data.id**

Comment: `data = data.object`?

Comment: It's a web-hook returned data so the `object` key in `data` object will come always so you've to use like `data.object.id`